# Ubuntu сервер Wordpress - нехватка ОЗУ

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане.
Поднял сайт на сервисе DigitalOcean(Wordpress, Ubuntu).
Взял самый дешевый тариф с 512 метрами оперативы.
Использованные плагины - bbpress, Lockdown WP Admin, Profile Builder, Restrict Widgets, Yoast SEO, WP-Mail-SMTP.
[image: обзор памяти]
На картинке выше использовано 446 метра из 512. 
Так же скриншот с самими процессами.
[image: обзор процессов]
Можно ли как нибудь оптимизировать, для увеличения количества свободной памяти?
Если нет, то при использовании свапа насколько примерно уменьшится производительность?
В интернете искал находил только увеличение производительности самого вордпресса.
С уважением, votanko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Что можно сделать в такой ситуации:
1) Добавить swap.
Производительность просядет объективно, в зависимости от ситуации - в разы.
Для разработки - думаю хватит
2) Покрутить настройки nginx, php-fpm (главное) в плане уменьшения к-ва запущенных процессов и т.д.
Это позволит тоже что-то высвободить.
3) Выключить ненужные сервисы.
Вот я увидел у Вас vsftpd 
Можно же спокойно работать через ssh, WP это умеет, только нужен плагин для php - php_ssh2

Comment: php-fpm (главное) ? об этом где можно почитать?

Comment: Начните с: http://habrahabr.ru/post/221803/ ("Чеклист по оптимизации VPS на PHP/Mysql/Nginx") и http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/ ("Nginx and PHP-FPM Configuration and Optimizing Tips and Tricks")

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли как нибудь оптимизировать, для увеличения количества свободной памяти?

Зачем? Что вам это даст, кроме циферок в `free`?

> Если нет, то при использовании свапа насколько примерно уменьшится производительность?

Вопрос, на который невозможно дать ответ, и перед которым надо еще задать вопрос "а будет ли использоваться swap?". ОС и запущенные программы едят столько оперативки, сколько доступно, держа часть этой оперативки в буфере и освобождая по мере необходимости. Вышеприведенная картина абсолютно нормальна. Что до PHP, на котором крутится вордпресс, то вы вообще этим не можете отследить использование оперативки, потому что PHP-приложения подыхают после окончания запроса (т.е. в течение секунды), и вышеприведенная статистика может быть получена как в момент прихода нескольких запросов, так и в то время, когда ни одного запроса не было, а потому абсолютно бесполезна. Вам не одномоментный вывод надо смотреть, а график, и вряд ли график использования, потому что, повторюсь, использование всей памяти еще не значит, что она закончилась - у вас же даже своп пустой, им вообще ни разу никто не воспользовался.

Comment: Т.е. получается сделать практически ничего нельзя? Все упирается в сам сервер, необходимо увеличить количество самой ОЗУ.  
Или все оставить как и есть?

Comment: @votanko господи, нет, вообще ничего не надо увеличивать. Пока у вас не падают скрипты с ООМ или нет подозрений на то, что дефрагментация памяти отнимает слишком много времени, вообще ничего делать не надо. Дроплета на DO спокойно хватает на вордпресс, даже несмотря на то, что разработчики сделали всё возможное, чтобы сожрать все доступые ресурсы.